# Thinking Sphinx and facets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a product table and a variants table

```
Product - title, description, id
Variant - id, product_id, size_label, qty, price

Product has_many variants
Variant belongs_to product
```

I have defined my product index like

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :product, :with => :active_record, delta: true do
  indexes title, facet: true
  indexes variants.size_label, as: :sizelabel, facet: true

  has variants.id, as: :variant_ids
  has variants.qty, as: :variant_qty
end
```

If I have product with 5 variants, eg with size_label S, M, L, XL, XXL then the sizelabel facet is returned as one string "S M L XL XXL"

Am I setting up the index wrong - expecting the variants to be returned as a separate hash (like other facets are)

Using Rails 3.2.19, Sphinx 2.1.9, Thinking Sphinx 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fields are aggregates (which is true of your size labels field), the values are concatenated together as a single string, as Sphinx only understands single string values for fields, not arrays.

Also, it's worth noting that while Sphinx does support single string value attributes, and multi-value integer/timestamp/bigint attributes, but *not* multi-value string attributes. So, what I'd propose is the following: pull size labels out into a separate table, then have size_label_id in your Variant model. Then, add the following attribute:

```
has variants.size_label_id, as: :size_label_ids, facet: true
```

When you get your facet results back, you'll need to translate them to the meaningful text. I've [written some code](https://gist.github.com/pat/5477820) that should be useful (though some adapting is likely required).

Comment: Thanks @pat  Worked great.